# Socket.io: check the status of a connection with the socket id

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a socket id of a connection. Can I get the status of that connection, inside the function handler of another one?

Something like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    /* having the socket id of *another* connection, I can
     * check its status here.
     */
    io.sockets[other_socket_id].status
}
```

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For versions higher than 1.0, check Karan Kapoor answer.
For older versions, you can access any connected socket with `io.sockets.sockets[a_socket_id]`, so if you've set a status variable on it, `io.sockets.sockets[a_socket_id].status` will work.

First you should check if the socket really exists, and it can also be used to check connected/disconnected statuses.

```
if(io.sockets.sockets[a_socket_id]!=undefined){
  console.log(io.sockets.sockets[a_socket_id]); 
}else{
  console.log("Socket not connected");
}
```

Comment: Nice way. I found another method to do it, and I'll add it as an answer. But I'll mark yours as accepted ;)

Comment: @franzlorenzon : what is the other way to check socketid is still connected?

Comment: I migrated to sockjs but that's how I did it. I took the clients with `io.sockets.clients()`. Then I iterated over the array, searching for the right socket (comparing the ids, `.id` property on a socket object). When I found it, I checked the `disconnected` property. For greater accuracy, I wrote a simple keepalive system to check if clients were alive.

Answer (score 6):

As of today, Feb, 2015, none of the methods listed here work on the current version of Socket.io (1.1.0). So on this version, this is how it works for me :

```
var socketList = io.sockets.server.eio.clients;
            if (socketList[user.socketid] === undefined){
```

the `io.sockets.server.eio.clients` is an array containing a list of all the live socket id's. So use the code in the if statement to check if a particular socket ID is in this list.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (io.sockets.connected[socketID]) { 
    // do what you want 
}
```

Comment: how does this let you get the status of the connection? It only seem to watch for the `connected` status, no others...

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io >= 1.0, as Riwels answer, first you should check if the socket exists

```
if(io.sockets.connected[a_socket_id]!=undefined){
    console.log(io.sockets.connected[a_socket_id].connected); //or disconected property
}else{
    console.log("Socket not connected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions, you can check `socket.connected` property.

```
var socket = io(myEndpoint)
console.log(socket.connected) // logs true or false
```

Also you can set timeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if(! socket.connected) {
        throw new Error('some error')
    }
}, 5000)
```

This checks if socket connected in 5 seconds.